# How do I replace willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge with new AFNetworking2

Tags: afnetworking-2

I have been tasked with converting NSURLConnection et al, with AFNetworking 2. My first roadblock is  in a custom authentication challenge.

I am confused on what replaces the delegate method willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge in AFNetworking 2.

A simple code example would be great.